# How to correctly extract .pem key from request response with JSON extrator

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am using a jmeter JSON extractor for a JSON that looks like this

```
{"type":"rpc","tid":7,"action":"SecurityManager","method":"getAuthenticationKey","result":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAydpVbheWPx4ZMbxJ8yCm\ndcP2EaRZD2R4PUmuFhdDdvpxT\/so00\/22orFQMgw8hrgEZ07ISzarOlclchm7DtF\nzxUzjGon1d5OJ2\/61niT+bAyuykn7y63\/BEtGS3KsR9ez3Ds+JR04Tca\/ajUYAIo\nrtAdCuvQuWkk4ZmZWywa7n899KOndL8S3G0R9Bex5XwfXJoE2BC6Ww75gwkzANFX\nIqkTYeepIMai3B8H31VIW2aJXURbjgN4yrk4sOy5a5JqnPEeCPKJR3nCrZDZGG06\ncoq0swW8oegNI9SFsiIqpDQ6Fi4WqqH5EMNu6FrkF3HAqwwyGljnogGNdnkwajiu\nCQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"}
```

I am trying to use that value (for example just show it)

```
log.info("${key}")
```

, but I get the error

```
    o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script26.groovy: 8: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 8, column 39.
log.info("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Is there something i am not doing right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use ${} in Groovy script in JMeter.

Instead do this:

> log.info("Got key:{}", vars["key"]);

Provided your variable is named key

And this is how you would configure [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

[image: JSON Extractor]

Comment: This works, but can you give any insight on why ${} should not be used in groovy script and why to use vars["key"]?

Answer (score 0):

Given you use JSR223 Test Elements already you don't need the JSON Extractor, the PEM key can be extracted and printed in one shot via [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('key', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).result)
   log.info(vars.get('key'))
   ```
3. Enjoy the printed variable in Log Viewer window

   [image: JMeter Print Variable into log]
4. Of course you will be able to access it as `${key}` in the other Test Elements

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

Going forward please avoid using JMeter functions and/or variables in Groovy scripts as they conflict with Groovy [GString Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html), may be resolved into something which cause compilation or runtime failure and non-compatible with Groovy caching of compiled scripts feature negatively impacting JMeter performance.